# How could I customize ColorRules or ColorFunction in MatrixPlot?

Tags: plotting, color

Hello and have a nice day!

I need to make MatrixPlot for some [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1guDjrQMtioCGRR2dtzaEJ5qJ38GiXo08/view?usp=sharing). [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-y-gKEebfJV4J_3Z3bsDISyRLCOJrS9P/view?usp=sharing) you can find a notebook with preprocessing raw data and some functions from below text.

**I want all "Inf" values to be colored white, those greater than 13 to be black, and for the rest a color gradient will be applied, and in the full range, and not in half.**

When I use

```
ColorRules -> {x_ /; x === Infinity -> White, x_ /; 13 < x -> Black }
```

it goes wrong

[image: MatrixPlot with ColorRules]

because range should be bigger

[image: BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, 13}}]]

The problem doesn't solved by writing customize ColorFunction:

```
myColorData[c_] := Function[Which[
# === Infinity, White,
# > 13, Black,
True, ColorData[c][N@##]
]];
```

with calling

```
MatrixPlot[Flatten[bottleneck, 1], PlotRange -> {0, 13},ColorFunction -> (myColorData["ThermometerColors"][##] &), ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

Thank you!
With respect!

Comment: Since you're turning off `ColorFunctionScaling`, you need to manually rescale. Try `...ColorRules -> {\[Infinity] -> White,  x_ /; x > 13 -> Black}, ColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[N@#, {Min@Flatten@bottleneck, 13}, {0, 1}]] &),
ColorFunctionScaling -> False...`

Comment: @n-j-evans thank you for your response

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't use the numbers in your file, so here is my best effort with random data.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
SeedRandom[1];
(amat = RandomChoice[
    Range[20]~Join~{∞}, {30, 30}]) // MatrixPlot

col[x_] := 
  If[x == ∞, White, 
   If[x > 13, Black, ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[x, {1, 13}]]]];

MatrixPlot[amat
 , ColorFunction -> col
 , ColorFunctionScaling -> False
 , PlotLegends -> {
   Placed[BarLegend[{col[#] &, {0, 14}}
     , LegendMarkerSize -> 134], {1.01, 0.4}]
   , Placed[SwatchLegend[{Black, White}, {"x>13", "∞"}
     , LegendLayout -> "ReversedColumn"
     , LegendMarkerSize -> 15
     ], {1.025, 0.7}]
   }
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, dear Syed! 